# Bash - how do you make it so that the result of a command gets placed into a variable?

Tags: bash

For instance, let's say I wish to type the command `pwd`.

It gives me a really long path to the current directory I am in.

What I would really like to do is make it so that I can go into a completely different directory and still refer to the previous directory I was in, without having to memorize the previous path.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You involve several different questions in one. :P
We'll cover variable assignment first.
To put the result of a command into a variable you can either use backticks `` or $() syntax. For example:

```
MYPWD=`pwd`
MYPWD=$(pwd)
```

For further information check the section *Command Substitution* in the bash(1) manual page. Easily available at: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

But if for your question is about changing to the previous directory bash has a built in syntax for this. Simply do a `cd -` and bash will take you to where you were.

```
# cd /usr/local/bin
# cd /var/log/apache2
# cd -
# pwd
/usr/local/bin
```

For more advanced directory/cd handling, check the manual page for `pushd` and `popd` that allows you to build a stack of directories that you can use.

Comment: Maybe also mention that `${OLDPWD}` is a variable that already contains the previous directory.

Comment: See: [How can I change to the previous directory instead of going up?](http://superuser.com/questions/324512/how-can-i-change-to-the-previous-directory-instead-of-going-up)