# How can I make my own "shell commands" (e.g. mkdir/cd combo)?

Tags: bash

I can't tell how many times I have wished for a command that would both create a directory and move to that directory. Basically, I would like the equivalent of the following:

```
mkdir -p /arbitrarily/long/path; cd /arbitrarily/long/path
```

but only having to type the `/arbitrarily/long/path` once, something like:

```
mk-cd /arbitrarily/long/path
```

I tried creating a script to do this, but it only changes the directory within the script. I'd like the directory in the shell to have changed as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $1
cd $1
export PWD=$PWD
```

How might I be able to make this work?

Comment: With `cd`, you picked a special case right from the start. :D

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but super cool `cd`-related info (return to the previous directory using `cd -`, use `pushd` and `popd` to maintain a "stack" of directories): http://superuser.com/questions/324512/how-can-i-change-to-the-previous-directory-instead-of-going-up

Comment: You can type `mkdir -p /very/long/path`, then use `cd`, space, and then press Alt+`.` to repeat the last argument, i.e. the dir name.

Comment: @choroba Nice trick. Reminds me of how in vim, you use `.` to repeat the last edit command.

Comment: Why might someone downvote this question? Just curious what I did that seems so obviously wrong.

Comment: Sometimes, questions and replies got downvotes without any obvious reason, especially when no comments are there to explain their motivations. Hopefully, one single positive vote, even undeserved ;-) is enough to balance ten negative ones so you shouldn't bother too much about it.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment similar to @choroba's: You can also use `mkdir -p /very/long/path; cd !#:2`. The string `!#:2` will expand to argument nr. 2 (that is, the third argument, `/very/long/path`, as counting starts with zero).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt That is so useful! `vim -p !#:0_notes !#:2.txt` becomes `vim -p vim_notes vim_notes.txt`

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt, even easier, since it's the last argument of the last command, you can just use `!$`.  I use this particular trick all the time, though [there is a lot more you can do with history expansion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275061/135943).

Comment: One final comment on `export` - you should never use `export var=$var` because: (1) the assignment is unnecessary, as `export var` does the job; and (2) the statement will fail if `var` contains a space. If you use `export var="$var"` the assignment will be unnecessary, but at least it will not fail.

Comment: See [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th/9124#9124) for a more robust version of this function (handling symbolic links, errors, etc.)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a shell function:

```
mkcd() {
    mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -- "$1"
}
```

Place it in your `.bashrc` file to make it be available to you just like another shell command.

The reason why it doesn't work as an external script is `cd` changes the current directory of the running script but doesn't affect the calling one. This is by design! Each process has its own working directory which is inherited by its children, but the opposite is not possible.

Unless part of a pipeline, run in the background or explicitly in a subshell, a shell function doesn't run in a separate process but in the same one, just like if the command has been sourced. The current directory shell can then be changed by a function.

The `&&` used here to separate both commands used means, if the first command succeeds (`mkdir`), run the second one (`cd`). Consequently, if `mkdir` fails to create the requested directory, there is no point trying to go into it. An error message is printed by `mkdir` and that's it.

The `-p` option used with `mkdir` is there to tell this utility to create any missing directory that is part of the full path of the directory name passed as argument. One side effect is that if you ask to create an already existing directory, the `mkcd` function won't fail and you'll end up in that directory. That might be considered an issue or a feature. In the former case, the function can be modified for example that way which simply warns the user:

```
mkcd() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        printf "mkcd: warning, \"%s\" already exists\n" "$1"
    else
        mkdir -p "$1" 
    fi && cd "$1"
}
```

Without the `-p` option, the behavior of the initial function would have been very different.

If the directory containing the directory to create doesn't already exists, `mkdir` fails an so does the function.

If the directory to be create already exists, `mkdir` fails too and `cd` isn't called.

Finally, note that setting/exporting `PWD` is pointless, as the shell already does it internally.

Edit: I added the `--` option to both commands for the function to allow a directory name starting with a dash.

Comment: You should also add that this command will not become permanently available unless it is added to `~/.bashrc` or one of the other initialisation scripts.

Comment: Is there no way in bash to do the equivalent of tcsh's `alias mk-cd 'mkdir -p \!:1; cd \!:1'` without a function? Or maybe I should start thinking of bash functions more like extended aliases?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy This `csh` argument passing mechanism is not implemented with bourne style aliases. Functions are indeed the way to go, being much more flexible.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy - You might like to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter/30357877#30357877), which does provide a rather abstruse mechanism for accessing parameters passed to an alias (in the definition of `bar`). Another option would be to use `history 1`, as in `alias mk-cd='args="$(history 1)" && args="${args#*mk-cd\ }" && mkdir -p "$args" && cd'` - this works fine for the questioner's example, but is not a general solution, as any other commands on the same line (eg piping the output) will cause it to fail.

Comment: I was just about to post this. Upvoted!

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy You should start thinking of tcsh's aliases more like restricted functions.

Answer (score 32):

I would like to add an alternative solution.

Your script *will* work if you invoke it with the `.`  or `source` command:

```
. mk-cd /arbitrarily/long/path
```

If you do this the `export` in the script is unnecessary. You can bypass typing the `.` by using an `alias`:

```
alias mk-cd='. mk-cd'
```

The reason this works is that a script normally runs in a sub-shell so its environment is lost on completion, but the `.` (or `source`) command forces it to run in the current shell.

This technique can be useful for command sequences which are too complex for a function or which are under development and are frequently edited: once the `alias` has been entered into `.bash_aliases`, you can edit the script at will without reinitialising.

Note the following:-

If you write a script which *must* be called with the `.`/`source` command, there are two ways to make sure of this:-

1. For some reason, a script invoked with `.`/`source` need not be executable, so simply remove this permission and the script either will not be found in "$PATH" or will give a permission error if invoked with an explicit path.
2. Alternatively, the following trick can be used at the head of the script:

```
bind |& read && { echo 'Must be run from "." or "source" command'; exit 1; }
```

This works because in a sub-shell `bind` issues a warning, though no error status: hence `read` is used to give an error on no input.

Comment: Thanks for the info on `.`. I have done `. .bashrc` countless times, but didn't know what exactly the `.` does. Is it similar to `export`?

Comment: @cst1992 - No, the commands are completely different: `export var` copies the internal variable `var` to the environment, where it is inherited and imported as a variable in any sub-shell, but it has no effect on a parent shell. Normally a sub-shell is created to run a script, and any changes it makes (including exported variables) are lost when it completes. In order for a script to set variables in a shell it has to run in that shell, and this is what the `.` command does: run the script without creating a sub-shell. Curiously, scripts run by `.` need not have executable permission.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd insist that you include this info in your post. This is useful, and frankly, comments have no guarantee that they'll be there tomorrow.

Comment: @cst1992 - I addressed the original question, but I don't want to clutter my answer with ancillary issues. If you were looking for an explanation of the `.` and `export` commands, the title of this question would not lead you to expect an answer here, so I'll let my answer stand as it is, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: +1 in general, but especially for the alias. I have a few scripts which need to be sourced and I always forget to run them that way. The alias takes care of that nicely.

Comment: @Joe - I have added a note with two ways to make sure a script is invoked with `.` or `source`.

Comment: @cst1992 - You may be interested that I have explained the `.` and `source` commands in detail in [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1075315/how-to-convert-an-unknown-file-to-mp3/1075394#1075394).

Comment: I use this technique for all my shell scripts which must be dotted because they need to affect the current shell process.  I name such scripts `.whatever`, similar to `.bashrc`.  The initial dot in the name reminds me to dot the script.  One additional advantage to using an alias+script combination rather than a function is that you load much less code into your shell via `.bashrc`.  The code is only loaded when it is run.  Only the alias "shim" is needed in `.bashrc`.

Comment: @jrw32982 - I made your point when I said "command sequences which are too complex for a function". You may also like to consider my notes about forcing a script to be used with `.`, removing the need to hide your scripts with a leading `.` in the name.

Comment: @AFH - Saw your notes and agree with them, except I think that **any** command complex enough to require a function is complex enough to put in a script and call via an alias.  I enjoyed the notes about trying to force a script to be called by sourcing.  I don't consider starting a script with a leading `.` to be hiding it although I know what you mean.  I very much dislike the "leading `.` hides a file" feature of `ls` and globbing, so all my uses of `ls` use `-A` to avoid that.

Answer (score 13):

Not a single command, but you don't have to retype all the path just use `!$` (which is the last argument from the previous command in the shell history).

Example:

```
mkdir -p /arbitrarily/long/path
cd !$
```

Answer (score 1):

By creating [aliases](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/command_aliases.htm). Very popular way to create your own commands.

You can create an alias on the fly:

```
alias myalias='mkdir -p /arbitrarily/long/path; cd /arbitrarily/long/path'
```

That's it. If you want to keep that alias permanently (not just the current session), then put that command in a dotfile (typically ~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bash_profile).

Comment: As the long directory name is hardcoded, this alias wouldn't be very useful unless this directory is regularily destroyed by some other process.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has already been suggested, I'd like to recommend [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck). It's a Python framework for streamlining your shell process by fixing mistakes. Inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/liamosaur/status/506975850596536320), all you have to do is type your configured alias (by default `fuck`) and it will attempt to correct your previous command. One of its corrections behaves as follows:

```
/etc $ cd somedir
bash: cd: No such file or directory
/etc $ fuck
mkdir somedir && cd somedir
/etc/somedir $
```