# How to convert an unknown file to MP3?

Tags: windows, file-types

I'm having trouble converting an unknown file type into MP3 so I can play it on VLC.

If I drag and drop it, it plays fine, but when I open it and attempt to choose VLC as its program, the "Always choose this program to open this kind of file" check box is grayed and I can't click it. I want to set VLC as the program for all of my music files that are like this.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: What is the extension of the file in question?

Comment: @VL-80 It is an unknown file type.

Comment: I am afraid in Windows you can not assign default applications for files without extension.

Comment: @VL-80 Is there a software which can do that?

Comment: @VL-80 Or maybe an app?

Comment: Try to add `.mp3` to the end of the filename. This will give your OS a hint that this file could be opened with the VLC player. Keep in mind - it might happen that it's actual format is not MP3, but something else. With file extension set, you will be able to define default app for this file.

Comment: @VL-80 I already did that. Although it converts the file to an mp3 file, but nothing gets played when I open it.

Comment: If you play the file by dragging and dropping, pause it, go to play-list, right-click on the file being played and click **Information...**. The **Codec** tab will tell you what kind of file it is, and you can rename to have an appropriate extension. Don't convert it! This will take time and degrade the quality. If you don't know what the appropriate extension should be, rename it to `FileName.vlc` and associate this extension with VLC.

Comment: @AFH Yes that method is taking some time. Would you mind writing this as an answer (and elaborating a little bit) so that I can upvote + accept it? I really liked your method.

Comment: @AFH EPIC!! I just did what you told (rename to .vlc) and it converted in a second. Thank you so much!!!! :D

Comment: @AFH Since your method has finally helped me, feel free to add that as an answer, so that I can accept it and other users (who face a similar problem) can get help.

Comment: @Henry Send the file to the email listed in my profile- I'll check the file and let you know what filetype it really is.

Comment: There is no "Playlist" button: it is an option in the `View` menu, with the short-cut `Ctrl-L` on my systems.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want MP3 format specifically? It's not the only _format which can be played,_ and not even the best of them (both in terms of quality/efficiency and patent encumbering).

Comment: "Although it converts the file to an mp3 file..." No, it doesn't convert anything. You literally only changed the file name, which programs use as a hint about what's in the file. Do yourself a favor and [disable](https://youtu.be/wxIIskKmUQA) the "Hide known extensions" setting. That will give you a clearer picture of what's going on. (I consider extension hiding to be one of the stupidest "features" ever, personally.)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you play the file by dragging and dropping, pause or stop it, then:

- go to play-list,
- right-click on the problem file, and
- click `Information...`

The `Codec` tab will tell you what kind of file it is, and you can now exit and rename the file to add an appropriate extension.

**Don't convert the file!** This will take time and degrade the quality. If you don't know what the appropriate extension should be, rename it to `FileName.vlc` and associate this extension with VLC (any unused extension could be used, but this one is unlikely to be used by anything else).

Comment: Or just rename all the files to ".mp3" (if .mp3 is associated with VLC) assuming VLC can sort it out that is :)

Comment: @rogerdpack - In the comments exchanged with VL-80, the questioner said that he had done this, and the file opened in VLC, but didn't play.

Comment: This. Never convert a file just to get file association to work.  Sheesh.  Hiding file extensions is the absolute worst thing microsoft ever did.  God forbid people understand how things work.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'm not sure it's the _absolute_ worst thing... However, it should be pointed out that converting to _MP3_ is lossy, but surely VLC can convert to better formats if desired.

Comment: @Auspex - Most audio and all video formats in common use are lossy. If you convert to another lossy format, nothing will restore what has already been lost, and further degradation will inevitably occur.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Well, arguably they should never have made the file type part of the filename in the first place.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Well, it's what people want.  The same reason Apple's devices don't give error codes.  You can hardly blame the companies for changing their products in line with consumer demand... the blame properly belongs on the consumers who (for example) explicitly don't want to understand even very basic things about how their computers work.

Comment: Fun Fact of the Day: Take your favorite `.xlsx` and change it to a `.zip` and open it with your archiving tool of choice. Extract some of the sheets and go to town with them. Lots of fun!

Comment: @HopelessN00b You cant blame every day users for that. The majority of people see computers as a means to an end, and not something to be understood and conquered, like most of us on Stack Exchange. Companies are required to cater to these users. Its their livelihood. The trick for these companies is to balance the two. Every day user, and the 'SuperUser'

Comment: @corsiKa Why would you have to change the extension before opening it with your archiving tool of choice?

Comment: @DavidConrad Interesting - I thought it would be a matter of the context menu, but having used my archiving tool of choice, 7zip, on an `xlsx` file, I see the context menu for opening is there. Nifty.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I wouldn't say that. After all, you can still turn them back on. Besides, Windows is aimed towards the simplest of users, and the techiest of users, and the simpler users may well be confused by file extensions (and if they're using XP and they rename the file, because XP highlights the file name *and* the extension, it's very easy to eliminate the extension by accident).

Answer (score 43):

**EDIT**
To anyone who has exactly the same problem: don't let my answer misguide you. AFH's answer is right, it is better not to convert. Still, OP asked for it, OP got it.

**Original answer:**
If VLC can play this file it probably can convert it. There is *convert/save* entry in *file* menu (I have Polish locale set; actual entry may be slightly different in English). Add your file with *add* button, then pick *convert* from dropdown menu at the bottom. My VLC has MP3 profile out of the box.

Comment: Sounds good! Let me just try that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by 'add' button? Thanks.

Comment: Ignoring? You need a little patience. :) I rarely use Windows. My VLC is on Ubuntu but i believe it is similar to windows version. I have *convert/save* in *file* menu, then there is *file* tab with file list (originally empty) and *add* button. Is windows version much different?

Comment: @Henry I have just installed brand new VLC on my old XP. It's all there. The shortcut is Ctrl+R.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are way too nice.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Let me give you a honorary [sportsmanship] badge for your attitude.

Comment: Note that while conversion may lower the audio quality, there are good reasons to convert anyway - the main reason being that many portable players or smartphone music apps support few formats. MP3 is the "safe" choice in these cases.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thanks for the endorsement.

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely *must* convert the file to mp3, I would recommend [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

You can convert your file on the command line:

`ffmpeg -i random-audio-file -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 foobar.mp3`

But as stated by others, if VLC can already play it, there's no need to convert it (and thus lose quality).

**It's better to identify the filetype or codec, and rename the file to the appropriate extension which you can then bind in Windows to open with VLC by default.**

To identify the filetype or audio format, you can use `ffprobe` (which is also part of ffmpeg). Or use various other tools such as [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) which is perhaps more user friendly, especially for Windows users.

Answer (score 3):

### Blind, quick and dirty.

You stated that yours is an mp3 file without the extension (vlc played it).
**You have not to convert it, you have simply to rename it adding the extension `.mp3`.**
If you convert it you will loose something in term of quality.

Note that even if it was not an *mp3 file* probably each version of VLC will play it anyway even if you rename it with a wrong extension. The problem, if present, will remain  but you will not be aware...

---

<sup>If you feel unconfortable reading the above answer maybe you want to read some lines more...</sup> 
... A *wiser* way to proceed is to **recognise** which kind of file it is and which tools can help you...
but **this is another *quest*(ion)**, many time asked, answered and closed before <sup>[[q1](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data)],[[q2](https://superuser.com/questions/435224/how-do-i-find-out-the-file-type-without-an-extension)]</sup> `:-)`.

It is often possible because many standards require identification codes in specific parts of the file, usually in the beginning. That is the reason because vlc can play even a part of a file (not yet fully downloaded).

More you know about the file more ideas car arise after. So what are your options?

- **Vlc** can do it, as suggested in another good answer <sup>[[1](https://superuser.com/a/1075394/257269)]</sup>.
- If you have many files, it can be time consuming to repeat with a GUI that operation each time.
   <sup>Many tools, as for example **TrID** <sup>[[2](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)]</sup>, can identify them for you and eventually automatically rename all the files.</sup>
- Unfortunately, windows 7 by default do not include the gnu **`file`** command <sup>[[3](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)]</sup>. But fortunately you can download and install it. Then from a shell (execute the program `cmd.exe`), you can arrive to your file (`cd yourpath`) then write the command

  ```
  file MyUnknowFile
  ```

  and it will answer with something like

  > Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: **MPEG** ADTS, **layer III**, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo

  I put in bold  **MPEG** and **layer III**... so this is an **mp3** file and  this is the extension that your file has somehow lost. You have only to add it to your file. 
  Do you remember *"more you know ... more ideas"*? I can read `with ID3` and that gives me another idea (see below).
- You can use an **ID3 tag *renamer*** <sup>[[q3](https://superuser.com/search?q=rename+id3)]</sup>, yes you can change not only the extension but even the *filename* compliant with the information included in the ID3 tag !
- You can use an [online service](http://www.1mtb.com/top-5-best-web-based-online-music-song-identification-services/) to identify the song. Some of them are able to overcome the wrong extension too...

But the path of an heroic champion pass through the hard way.
The way of the paladin is to see the binary (maybe the hexadecimal) code of your file in search of the *magic numbers* <sup>[[w1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)]</sup> looking in a *reference table* <sup>[[w2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)]</sup> to understand which file is... and eventually re-invent the wheel. `:-)`.