# Numerous FLAC files in my music library will play only with VLC - can anything be done?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, compact-disc, flac

I discovered today after upgrading and rebuilding some server hardware that Plex, Windows Media Server, and this new "Groove" thing won't play some of my FLAC files I ripped from CDs. These files weren't touched and other FLAC files on the same drive play fine.

Since the size seems fine, I tried playing in VLC - and they play fine! From the file dates, it seems like rips from only several days around 7/4/2011 have been affected.  mp3tag also seems to see the embedded metadata  (title, album art, comment with freedb id, etc) fine, but windows doesn't.

I used EAC back then (and actually probably still would for the few new CDs I buy).  I could re-rip but my CDs are super-disorganized.  Any ideas what could be wrong with these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anything be done?

[If VLC can play this file it probably can convert it](https://superuser.com/a/1075320/432690), so convert your problematic files to… FLAC maybe.

If there's any problem with this approach, you may try to convert to another *lossless* format and then back to FLAC with *another* tool.

> Any ideas what could be wrong with these files?

At the moment I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks Kamil!  I used the convert functions of VLC to do exactly as you suggested, saving again as a FLAC.  This time, both VLC *and* the other players were able to successfully decode the file.  It was also a bit larger and none of the tags were showing in mp3tag anymore.  Still curious, I used gvim to edit both and saw ID3 tags in the bad files!  I must have changed my EAC settings for some days back then.  A hydrogenaudio post sad: You can rewrite tags using MP3Tag. Add files to MP3Tag, Select all files, Right click->Tag Cut, Yes, OK. Then again Right click->Tag Paste, Yes, OK.  All at once