# Command line, go back to last directory

Tags: cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Go back to previous directory in shell](https://superuser.com/questions/113219/go-back-to-previous-directory-in-shell)
>   [How can I change to the previous directory instead of going up?](https://superuser.com/questions/324512/how-can-i-change-to-the-previous-directory-instead-of-going-up)

is there a command line way to navigate back to the directory I was in?

I frequently do `cd ..` to go up a directory, but sometimes I accidentally just do `cd` which takes me to the user's home directory.

I want to go back to the directory I was just in, without navigating all the way through the nested folders or without typing the whole path out, which can be very long and prone to errors

I am specifically using OSX,  but `cd` is pretty universal

Comment: Try tipying a cd /? on your OSX. I did it on Windows but cd don't have such feature.

Comment: @Diogo That command does not work on OS X (or any Unix/Linux).

Comment: @slhck I never used OSX so I really dont know.. My intent was to tell to type a cd -help or something like this to show cd manual.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

On *nix systems, you can type `cd -` to return to the previous directory. Doesn't work on Windows, though.

Comment: it does on git bash for windows (at least now in 2019). thanks for the tip

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi 'cd ..\' goes up to the parent directory, not back to the previous directory.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
cd -
```

That works in Bash.  It may work in your shell too.